# Laravel AJAX and pagination with no url

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination

I have table displaying many rows, and I'm using pagination and sort function, also I'm using ajax to return number of rows and other ajax to return rows between two dates.

The problem is if I wanted to sort rows and in the same time show some rows between two dates this wont work with me. Because when using ajax there is no url.

```
public function index()
{
    $checks = Checks::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $checks= Checks::sortable()->paginate(10);
    return view('home',compact('checks'));
}

public function showpage(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $checks= Checks::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($request->inputpage);
        return view('layouts.showcheks',compact('checks'));  
    }
}

public function getCheckReport(Request $request)
{ 
    if($request->ajax()){
        $New=$request->StartDate;
        $Old=$request->EndDate;
        $checks= Checks::whereBetween('postingdate',[$New,$Old])->sortable()->orderBy('postingdate', 'asc')->get();
        return view('layouts.showcheks',compact('checks')); 
    }
}
```

**showchecks.blade.php**

```
@foreach($checks as $indexKey => $check)
    <tr >
        <td>{{$check->details}}</td>
        <td>{{date('m/d/Y', strtotime($check->postingdate))}}</td>
        <td>{{$check->description}}</td>
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

**homepage:**

```
<table class="table" id="postTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@sortablelink('details','Details')</th>
            <th>@sortablelink('postingdate','Date')</th>
            <th>@sortablelink('description','Description')</th>
        </tr>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($checks as $indexKey => $check)
        <tr >
            <td>{{$check->details}}</td>
            <td>{{date('m/d/Y', strtotime($check->postingdate))}}</td>
            <td >{{$check->description}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{{$checks->appends(Request::input())->links()}}
```

Comment: use datatable instead of normal table. inbuid functions there. do all the comparisons in inside row

Comment: Where is the part in which you pass the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a datatable https://datatables.net/ with ajax that is the best way also u can sorting a rows also..

Comment: datatables conflict with my css design

Comment: try to add first datatables csss then add your own csss